# Convert strings to list Python

Tags: python, string, list

```
list_val = '["apple", "blue", "green", "orange", "cherry", "white", "red", "violet"]'

print type(list_var)
str

print type(list_var[0])
'['
```

I read list_val values from a file and how to convert list_var to list ? so that list_var [0] should be 'apple'.

Comment: Why not configure list_val as list and for each value, just append the item to the list?

Comment: How did the file end up like that in the first place? Are you trying to remember some list contents between runs of the program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> list_val = '["apple", "blue", "green", "orange", "cherry", "white", "red", "violet"]'
>>> 
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> list_val = literal_eval(list_val)
>>> list_val[0]
'apple'
```

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you use `json`.

```
import json
list_val = '["apple", "blue", "green", "orange", "cherry", "white", "red", "violet"]'
a = json.loads(list_val)
print a
# [u'apple', u'blue', u'green', u'orange', u'cherry', u'white', u'red', u'violet']
print type(a)
# <type 'list'>
print a[0]
# 'apple'
```

Comment: This certainly works for the example input. The best choice depends on matching the source encoding to the decoder. The origin may very well be JSON in this case.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) function. Be careful what you pass to eval though, malicious things can happen!

```
list_var = eval(list_val)
```

Comment: eval is evil please use `literal_eval` instead

Answer (score 1):

Another way is using regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> list_val = '["apple", "blue", "green", "orange", "cherry", "white", "red", "violet"]'
>>> result = re.findall(r'\"([^\"]+)\"', list_val)
>>> result[0]
'apple'
```